# Book about protagonist, Cassia, taken on as a wizard's apprentice

Tags: story-identification, books

I know the main character was Cassia. I think they called her Kiska or Ciska affectionately.

Her type of magic was shunned, but wizards were revered. She was taken on as an apprentice type by a head wizard type who eventually goes bad. She puts together pieces of knowledge to blend elements to travel distances and time. She eventually helped the king.

She had a son (Beya? Benya? Beyja?) and a love interest in the book. There was also a historical character named Marija Ohdani or Odahni?

This wasn't a best seller by any means as far as I remember, and I believe this was in the 90's but I'm not positive.

Answer (score 7):

The book is probably [*The Spirit Gate*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671877127) by Maya Kaathryn Bohnhoff.

- It was published in 1996
- The protagonist is named Kassia Telek
- She has a son named Beyla
- Kassia has control over both types of available magic in the world

[image: Book cover]

Comment: Holy amazeballs Batman! Thank you!